# Tableのヘッダ固定、列固定

Tags: javascript, css

Excelの「ウィンドウ枠の固定」のようにTableのヘッダ行や列を固定したいです。
colspanやrowspanを用いてセル結合しているTableでも適用可能な手法やライブラリはあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

マークアップ済みの `table` 要素に少し細工するレベルでは実現できないので、[Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/index.html) を使うのはどうでしょうか。

### 詳細

「あらかじめマークアップ済みの、一つの `table` 要素で表現されるテーブルに対して」という前提を置く場合、ヘッダ行の固定だけであれば CSS の `float` プロパティをうまく使えばできますが (「ヘッダ固定 thead float」などでググると出てくるはず) 、それと同時に行の固定、さらに `colspan` ・ `rowspan` 属性を用いる条件下では、多分実現方法はないです。

ヘッダ行や列の固定をするためには、次の4つの領域を表す **別々の `table` 要素** を組み合わせて表現する方法がよく採られているように思います。

1. 固定ヘッダ行部
2. 固定列部
3. 固定ヘッダ行と固定列の重複部
4. スクロール可能部

その上で、JavaScript でスクロール可能部の `scroll` イベントの発火に合わせてスクロールの追従が必要な領域をスクロールさせることで一応実装できます。ですがセルの縦幅・横幅を合わせたり、スクロールを制御するのは正直かなり面倒臭いです。

[Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/index.html) は上記の4つの `table` 要素を使うアイデアで実装されており、その `table` 要素内には `colspan` ・ `rowspan` 属性も使われています (http://handsontable.com/demo/merge_cells.html) 。
ただし、ライブラリを使う場合はJavaScriptでデータを入力する必要があるため、あらかじめHTMLをマークアップしておくことはできません。

なお、その他の高機能なテーブル関連のライブラリ ([SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) など) は、`table` 要素を使わずに各セルを `div` 要素で表現しているものが多いです。そのようなライブラリでは `colspan` ・ `rowspan` 属性のような効果を得ることができません。

Answer (score 2):

スプレッドシートが必要なプロダクトで[Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/demo/scroll_window.html)というライブラリを使った事があります。

ただしモバイル対応が不完全なので、有償でもよければ[Wijmo](http://wijmo.c1.grapecity.com/)の[SpreadJS](http://wijmo.c1.grapecity.com/widgets/wijmo-enterprise/spreadjs/)などを使った方がいいかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 1):

jQueryのtbodyScrollというプラグインやjquery.tablefix.jsというものがあるようです。

jquery.tablefix.js：http://www.otchy.net/javascript/tablefix/

Answer (score 1):

テーブルのヘッダー固定は、軽いのから重いのまで色々なライブラリがありますが、
どれも一長一短な気がしますねー。

軽いのだと、このあたりとか
[fixedTblHdrLftCol](http://webkaru.net/jquery-plugin/fixedtblhdrlftcol/) ( jQuery plugin )

重いのだと、このあたりとか
[SmartClient](http://smartclient.com/product/smartclient.jsp) ( 無料で使えるExt.jsのようなもの )
View hands on demo → Live Grid でデモを見れます。

Answer (score 1):

[FixedMidashi](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA056612/fixed_midashi/manual/index.html)というものもあるようです。

ドキュメントが日本語。

rowspan 属性を使っても問題ないようです。colspanは未確認。（http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA056612/fixed_midashi/manual/demo_div_full_iframe.html） 
Handsontable と似た実装なのかもしれません。